# How to replace underscores in codeigniter url with dashes?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I would like to know the simplest solution to changing the underscores of my codeigniter urls to dashes, for seo reasons.

My controllers look like:

```
public function request_guide() {
...Load view etc...
}
```

So to browse to this page I would have to go to:

```
www.domain.com/request_guide
```

But I want to be more seo friendly and use dashes instead of underscores, like so:

```
www.domain.com/request-guide
```

I am under the impression that codeigniter functions require underscores (might be wrong).

In previous projects I have simply used mod_rewrite but I believe that these actions can be performed using routes.

What is the easiest way for me to rewrite the urls replacing the underscores with dashes???

Comment: `request-guide` is not more seo-friendly than `request_guide`.

Comment: If you thik about it, that would match a class name, where a dash isn't valid; you would need, in fact, to write the class (or method) name as "request-guide", which is invalid php syntax. Go for a re-routing as suggested in answers below

Comment: I was under the impression from google that they class dashes as spaces and words containing underscores as a whole word.

Comment: @Ianzz request-guide is MUCH more seo-friendly than request_guide. Hyphens are extremely SEO friendly in URLs and Google interprets them as word separators.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The routes config found in

```
config/routes.php
```

is your friend here.

A simple

```
$route['request-guide'] = "request_guide" ;
```

will do this for you.

Answer (score 51):

It really depends on your intention. If you just want to change only one page, then **devrooms**' solution is the perfect one indeed:

```
$route['request-guide'] = "request_guide";
```

But if you want to make this your website's default behavior you should extend your core Router class like this (source: [[Using hyphens instead of underscores in CodeIgniter]](http://www.daveblencowe.com/2011/07/03/using-hyphens-instead-of-underscores-in-codeigniter/))

1. Make a new file in 'application/core' and name it 'MY_Router.php'
2. Insert this code in it:

   ```
   <?php

   defined('BASEPATH') || exit('No direct script access allowed');

   class MY_Router extends CI_Router {

       function _set_request ($seg = array())
       {
           // The str_replace() below goes through all our segments
           // and replaces the hyphens with underscores making it
           // possible to use hyphens in controllers, folder names and
           // function names
           parent::_set_request(str_replace('-', '_', $seg));
       }

   }

   ?>
   ```

**UPDATE (Oct 26, 2015)**: There's a better way to do this in CodeIgniter 3, as @Thomas Wood mentioned:

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to working now. created the file as above but nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: @LiveEn You need to include it on every page. I suggest auto loading it. Also don't include the closing '?>'... it's bad practice.

Comment: I thought they were forcing closed PHP tags in PHP6?

Comment: this solution is great the only problem is that it doesn't disable  **underscores (_)**; request-guide and request_guide now both work

Comment: an additional problem with this solution is that if you have anything that should have a dash in the url, say a parameter, it'll replace it with _ and that'll break any code which relies on the data using dashes and not underscore.  so any extension to this idea which only acts on controller/methods would leave the "data" alone, would be better

Comment: I think this might be a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428134/codeigniter-routes-regex-using-dashes-in-controller-method-names

Comment: @christopher-thomas Thanks for the suggestion! I think that solution is too much writing for doing something that could be done with just one line of code.

Comment: the good thing about the link i suggested, is that it works ONLY on classes and methods, so it doesn't touch the other parts of the url, for example, if you have parameters on the end with - in them, they'll get converted too.  This way only converts the parts which are needed, so even if it's a few more lines, it's actually more targetted and overall more complete

Comment: shouldnt it be set to TRUE?

Answer (score 29):

Code Ignitor 3 has this in built:

`$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;`

Just change to `TRUE` and you can use either `_` or `-`.

[Documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=translate_uri_dashes)

Comment: I am not sure, but it still exists in the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=translate_uri_dashes) (right down the bottom)

Comment: This seems **not to be working** if you have controllers inside directories or folders like `application/controllers/my_folder/About_us.php`.

Answer (score 10):

Open application/config/routes.php and change

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

Now when you access [www.domain.com/**request-guide**](http://www.domain.com/**request-guide**), it will instantiate **request_guide** controller.

It will work with all controllers with name containing _ (underscore).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Codeigniter's custom routing http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 2):

```
$route['request-guide'] = "request_guide";
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is create a custom hook (PST... you need basic CodeIgniter skills):
for more information regarding CodeIgniter [Hooks - Extending the Framework Core](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html)

```
/*
 * the hooks must be enabled from the config file
 * replace underscore with dashes (hyphens) for SEO
 */

function prettyurls() {
    if (is_array($_GET) && count($_GET) == 1 && trim(key($_GET), '/') != '') {
        $newkey = str_replace('-', '_', key($_GET));
        $_GET[$newkey] = $_GET[key($_GET)];
        unset($_GET[key($_GET)]);
    }
    if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']))
        $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = str_replace('-', '_', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
        $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = str_replace('-', '_', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    if (isset($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']))
        $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] = str_replace('-', '_', $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']);
    if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace('-', '_', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

I named the file **customhooks.php**.

Then add this to the hooks.php file in **application/config**:

```
$hook['pre_system'] = array(
    'class' => '',
    'function' => 'prettyurls',
    'filename' => 'customhooks.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params' => array()
);
```

You will need to edit your **application/config/config.php** file to enable hooks

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

**EXTRA:**

so that when you use **$this->uri->uri_string()** it stays hyphenated do the following [Creating Core System Classes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)

```
class MY_URI extends CI_URI {

    function uri_string() {
        return str_replace('_', '-', $this->uri_string);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this _remap() method to handle such behavior. Place this method in your controllers or create a core controller and place it in.

```
public function _remap($method, $params = array()){
    if(method_exists($this, $method)){
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
    }else{
        $method = str_replace("-", "_", $method);
        if(method_exists($this, $method)){
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
        }
    }
    show_404();
}
```