# Redirect & Route wildcard URL - with underscores to hyphens

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I'm using **CodeIgniter** and I needed to redirect several urls with underscores to their equivalent with hyphens.

> /some-controller --> /some_controller

I've partially solved this issue by tweaking the `config/routes.php` file.

**The thing is :**

How would I expand that to a Controller's function WITH a parameter.

Let's say I've got a controller `some_controller` (`some-controller` redirects to `some_controller`) and a function `func` in it (optionally taking a param).

```
$route['some-controller'] = 'some_controller';
$route['some-controller/func'] = 'some_controller/func';
```

This works. But, what if I have `some-controller/func/someparam`. (and `someparam` can be anything).
How could this redirect be implemented?

**Basically what I need is a redirection from :**

```
some-controller/func/*
```

**to**

```
some_controller/func/*
```

Any ideas?

---

**Hint :**

I don't need anything complicated like this one (
[How to replace underscores in codeigniter url with dashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052245/how-to-replace-underscores-in-codeigniter-url-with-dashes) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadn't searched enough - I admit it (it's one of those issues that always seem more complicated than they should be) :

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

```
$route['some-controller/func/(:any)'] = "some_controller/func/$1";
```

Or you could use `(:num)`, if what you're expecting is a number...