# CodeIgniter and htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-2

I have a controller named (for example) **TheLink**, and I can normally access it through **mywebsite/index.php/TheLink**. Is it possible to make a RewriteRule in htaccess to access it via **mywebsite/index.php/The-Link** without it redirecting to TheLink? So basically what I want it the URL to say **mywebsite/index.php/The-Link** (with dash) but use the TheLink controller.
I've tried

> RewriteRule ^The-Link$ index.php/TheLink
>   [L]

but that just redirects me to the default CodeIgniter 404 Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently this problem has nothing to do with htaccess and is solved in a completely different way. Solution found here:

[Codeigniter Routes regex - using dashes in controller/method names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428134/codeigniter-routes-regex-using-dashes-in-controller-method-names/2432405#2432405)

Edit: Also, a number of different solutions for this, including the one above, found here:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/forums/viewthread/124396/

Answer (score 1):

```
# To remove index.php from URL

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Additionally if website is hosted in another directory not just root, add this:

```
RewriteBase /some_directory/
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but that wasn't what I asked. My question was how to use dashes in the URL since controller classes obviously can't be named with dashes.
Example: desired URL: .../My-Link/ ---- Controller name: MyLink