# I need a regex to replace underscore by hyphen

Tags: regex, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a problem with my application. I use CodeIgniter for my project and it's forbidden to use hyphen in classname (underscores are allowed). But I want to separate words in URLs by hyphens. So I need to rewrite urls by a regex to replace underscores by hyphens in htaccess file.
Ideas?

For example :

I have many links :

- `domain.tld/I_need_help`
- `domain.tld/I_need_regex`

I want to have :

- `domain.tld/I-need-help`
- `domain.tld/I-need-regex`

In htaccess file, there should be :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a long search. I have the solution :

Go to [Codeigniter Routes regex - using dashes in controller/method names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428134/codeigniter-routes-regex-using-dashes-in-controller-method-names)

Comment: Remove the `R` flag. (Changing your links from `_` to `-` does seem to be backward? The hyphen is generally preferable.)

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to use routes to change url as you want.

`$route['link-to_something'] = 'class_name/some_function';`

after your edit:
try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I have many links and I must rewrite every link. You don't have  a regex for all links ?

Comment: I'm not sure you need regex at all. Try to explain your problem including code or something

Comment: the one, hardcode way should be like changing your base_url function to change underscores to dashed before returning the result. This would work if you are using all your links with `base_url()` function

Comment: Euh ? I don't understand. My base_url() is empty but it should contain domain.tld. Not after domain.tld.

Comment: you should use all your links like `base_url('link-to/another-segment)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using regex when you can achieve this by changing just the one line?

Open application/config/routes.php and change

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

That is it you need to do.