# CodeIgniter routing - change underscores to dashes

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'd like some help please.

I have set up some routes like this:

```
$route['controller/some-method/(:any)'] = 'controller/some_method/$1';
```

I was wondering if it is a more efficient way of doing this, instead of typing all of my routes one at the time, like creating a single route where all the controller or method names that have underscores make them dashes.

So basically what I want is to set all my urls to have dashes instead of underscores.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter Routes regex - using dashes in controller/method names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428134/codeigniter-routes-regex-using-dashes-in-controller-method-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Codeigniter Specifications, changing the following line to `TRUE` in routes.php will translate underscores to dashes.

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

[Codeigniter API Docs - Routing](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)