# Why generating SEO friendly URL is not working using routes in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, url-routing

I am developing an application using Codeigniter,and I am trying to generate SEO friendly URLs but nothing is working fine.

I have tried the following code in `routes` file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['add-quiz']     = 'main/add_quiz/';
$route['category-wise-questions/(:any)']    = 'category_wise_questions/$1';
```

Eventhough it generates:

> http://localhost/appname/main/add_quiz

instead of:

> http://localhost/appname/main/add-quiz

Comment: on the third line replace 'main/add_quiz/' by 'main/add-quiz/'

Comment: its not working,still showing the same thing

Comment: So if your are using `http://localhost/appname/main/add-quiz` it's show 404, but `http://localhost/appname/main/add_quiz` is working?

Comment: yes its working fine,not getting affected

Comment: What do you mean by "generate"? Routes don't generate links, they only process requested URIs.

Comment: try using http://localhost/appname/add-quiz 
this should work for you

Answer (score 0):

You are using routes that don't change the url, only routes the URL to a specific controller, when you do:

```
$route['add-quiz']     = 'main/add_quiz/';
```

The only thing you are doing is telling CI to direct the url: "add_quiz" to the controller "add-quiz" (instead of "add_quiz").

To make it work, you need to add a line in .htaccess, like:

```
RewriteRule /main/add-quiz /main/add_quiz [L]
```

Resulting in something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] #remove index.php
    RewriteRule /main/add-quiz /main/add_quiz [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then, all requests to '`main/add_quiz`' will be changed to '`main/add-quiz`'. If your controller is called: '`add_quiz`' you should preserve your route.php.

Maybe you should adapt the .htaccess file to your local/remote project with some change to make it work.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`$route['main/add-quiz'] ='main/add_quiz/';` Should work. 
 I have tried something like:
`$route['mumbai/piles-doctor'] = 'mumbai/piles_doctor';` which has worked perfectly.

> No need to update .htaccess.

Also make sure, `translate_uri_dashes` is set to its default value 'False'.
`$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE`;

> Though others can refer a better solution here [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428134/codeigniter-routes-regex-using-dashes-in-controller-method-names#answer-2432405)